# The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable

Tags: azure, foreach, terraform, azure-storage-account

I'm new to Terraform, I'm building Azure Infrastructure using Terraform.

Here's my `main.tf` file.

```
module "azResourceGroup" {
  source              = "./Modules/ResourceGroup"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags
}

module "azStorageAccount" {
  source              = "./Modules/StorageAccount"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  for_each                  = var.storage_account_list
  storage_account_name      = each.value.storage_account_name
  account_kind              = each.value.account_kind
  account_tier              = each.value.storage_account_tier
  enable_https_traffic_only = each.value.enable_https_traffic_only
}
```

This is the variable used for Storage Account (from `variables.tf` file) :

```
variable "storage_account_list" {
  type = list(object({
    storage_account_name      = string
    account_tier              = string
    account_kind              = string
    enable_https_traffic_only = bool
  }))
}
```

And below is the value for the variable (from `terraform.tfvars` file)

```
storage_account_list = [
  {
    storage_account_name      = "my-storage"
    account_tier              = "Standard"
    account_kind              = "BlobStorage"
    enable_https_traffic_only = false
  }
]
```

On the `terraform plan` command, I'm getting this below error. Please help me with this.

```
 Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on main.tf line 13, in module "azStorageAccount":
│   13:   for_each                  = var.storage_account_list
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.storage_account_list is list of object with 1 element
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have
│ provided a value of type list of object.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a list of objects in `for_each`. Only list of strings (no other type), or maps. So in your case you can change your list into map as follows:

```
module "azStorageAccount" {
  source              = "./Modules/StorageAccount"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  for_each                  = {for idx, val in var.storage_account_list: idx => val}

  storage_account_name      = each.value.storage_account_name
  account_kind              = each.value.account_kind
  account_tier              = each.value.storage_account_tier
  enable_https_traffic_only = each.value.enable_https_traffic_only
}
```

Comment: Minor correction that `list(string)` is also not allowed and would need to be `set(string)`, and that `list(object)` --> `set(object)` is an allowed value type for the `for_each` meta-arg if part of a dynamic block.

Comment: I think it's important to note that using the list index as a `for_each` key makes this essentially the same as using `count`, and so therefore may not be a suitable key to use depending on how the elements of that list ought to relate to instances of this module.